# Java - Execute a query sent from the Client to the Server with MySQL integrated

Tags: java, mysql

I have to send a string from the client to the server based on user input and execute this string as a query for a MySQL database. This is my server:

```
public class Server{
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String inputLine;
private static int port = 63400;

public static void main(String[] args){
    // Wait for client to connect on 63400
    try{
        System.out.println("Starting the socket server at port:" + port);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("You're now connected to the server.");

        //START of DB connection
        try{
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to MySQL...");

            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"); //Load the driver
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tvschedule", "user", "password"); //Connect

            if(conn == null){
                System.out.println("MySQL Server is NOT running!");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Successfully connected to MySQL!");
            }

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            try{
              stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
              while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                  resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(inputLine); 
              }
              while (resultSet.next()) {
                  System.out.print("Show Title: "+resultSet.getString("show_title"));
              }
            } catch(SQLException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
              try{
                if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
                if(resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
                if(conn != null) conn.close();
              } catch(SQLException e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
        } catch (Exception err){System.out.println(err);}
        //END of DB connection

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Some exception: " + e);
    }
}
}
```

And this is the client:

```
public class Client{
private static Socket socket;
private static PrintWriter printWriter;
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        socket = new Socket("localhost",63400);

        System.out.println("Enter Query to execute:");
        sc.nextLine(); //Expecting the user to hit "enter" when done

        printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        printWriter.println(sc);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Let's say I have to execute a SELECT query, I enter this in the console from the client side of the application:

```
SELECT show_title FROM shows WHERE show_id=1
```

and all I get is this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p+][position=46][match valid=true][need input=fals' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
at Server.main(Server.java:54)
```

Does this error have something to do with the way I input the query or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your client is wrong, it is sending the `toString()` output of the `Scanner`:

```
printWriter.println(sc);
```

translates to:

```
new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream()).println(new Scanner(System.in).toString());
```

Additionally, having a server execute arbitrary SQL is a bad idea, rather have predefined actions coded that can be called by sending a few parameters

ex:

```
action=get_results
id_x=2
```

set the parameters with `PreparedStatement`

Comment: I read about PreparedStatement but I don't think it's going to be of much use in my case. I have to be able to execute different queries, and not just similar to the example I gave. That's if I have understood correctly your answer.